# how can function called from another class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I want to make one generic class for all my button click methods. My button click method works properly in same aspx.cs file but when I want to call this method from generic class. But parameter is not passing. Can someone please help me. Here is my code.

*This is base class*

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Singnup : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void SUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Webapplication2.program.Insert_RData(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

*This is 2nd class where from i want to call button method*

```
namespace Webapplication2
{
    public class program : WebApplication1.Singnup
    {
        public static void Insert_RData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con_Signup = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
            con_Signup.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd_check = new SqlCommand("Check_Existing_Email", con_Signup);
            cmd_check.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd_check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail",EmailId);
            object i = cmd_check.ExecuteScalar();

            if (i != null)
            {
                lbforerror.Text = "This Email is already Registered";
                lbforerror.Visible = true;
            }
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing information from an instantiated class `Singup` to a static class `program`. The labels, etc will *not be available* from a static class, as it has no connection to the actual label.

If you want to separate the button click actions, AND you want them to access form elements (such as `lbforerror` then i suggest you use a partial class *or* simply use a Region within the same class to clean up the logic

```
#region Button Logic
//Your logic here
#endregion //button logic
```

The best way, is to separate the re-useable logic into a completely different class (in this case, handling the insertion) which returns the result, and is decisioned in your original class:

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    public object InsertRData(string EmailId)
    {
        SqlConnection con_Signup = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
        con_Signup.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd_check = new SqlCommand("Check_Existing_Email", con_Signup);
        cmd_check.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd_check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", EmailId);
        object i = cmd_check.ExecuteScalar();
        return i;
    }
}
```

Then your original class can simply say

```
public partial class Singnup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void SUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionManager mgr = new ConnectionManager();
        object i = mgr.Insert_RData("email logic here");
        if (i != null)
        {
            lbforerror.Text = "This Email is already Registered";
            lbforerror.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Singnup : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void SUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string EmailId = "yourmailid@domain.com";
            Webapplication2.program.InsertRData(EmailId);
        }
    }
}

namespace Webapplication2
{
    public class program : WebApplication1.Singnup
    {
        public static void Insert_RData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string EmailId = "yourmailid@domain.com";
            InsertRData(EmailId);
        }

        public static void InsertRData(string EmailId)
        {
            SqlConnection con_Signup = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
            con_Signup.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd_check = new SqlCommand("Check_Existing_Email", con_Signup);
            cmd_check.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd_check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", EmailId);
            object i = cmd_check.ExecuteScalar();

            if (i != null)
            {
                lbforerror.Text = "This Email is already Registered";
                lbforerror.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```